# Return image from SQL database using ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I'm trying to build Web API that returns images from my SQL database but I'm facing issues with the path of my image that says:

> couldn't find a part of the path

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is not clear about the message in the exception? Did you check whether the path exists?

Comment: actually, i copied this code from one of the tutorials and i dont understand what path or in which format should i provide in this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `image` folder, did it come with a capital letter? Because your code is displaying `Image` not `image`.

Comment: i dont have this folder, the images are stored in sql database, how can i specify their path? sorry im new to this technology and i hope u get what im writing

Comment: thank you i just solved it, i didnt have the folder called Images, just created and worked fine